# Merge/Concatenate two videos with different frame rates using FFmpegFrameGrabber & FFmpegFrameRecorder javacv in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, video, ffmpeg, frame-rate, javacv

I am trying to merge/concatenate 2 videos. One of the videos has a frame rate of 0.25fps and the other has a frame rate of 30fps. When I merge the two videos using FFmpegFrameGrabber & FFmpegFrameRecorder javacv libraries, the second video becomes slowed down and looks like a slow motion video and the length of the second video increases drastically. I was hoping to know what I need to do in order to keep the videos in their respective frame rates and merge them both without altering none of them. I have attached the code below for reference:

```
FFmpegFrameGrabber video1Grabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber("video-test1.mp4");
        video1Grabber.start();

        FFmpegFrameGrabber video2Grabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber("video-test2.mp4");
        video2Grabber.start();

        URL url = new URL(S3Urls.AUDIO_DREAMY);
        BufferedInputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
        FileOutputStream fileOS = new FileOutputStream("dreamy-audioFile.mp3");
        byte data[] = new byte[1024];
        int byteContent;
        while ((byteContent = inputStream.read(data, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
            fileOS.write(data, 0, byteContent);
        }

        FFmpegFrameGrabber audioGrabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber("dreamy-audioFile.mp3");
        audioGrabber.start();

        FFmpegFrameRecorder audioRecorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder("audio-output.mp3", audioGrabber.getAudioChannels());
        audioRecorder.setSampleRate(audioGrabber.getSampleRate());
        audioRecorder.start();

        Frame audioFrame;
        while ((audioFrame = audioGrabber.grab()) != null) {
            audioRecorder.record(audioFrame);
        }
        audioRecorder.stop();

        FFmpegFrameGrabber finalAudio = new FFmpegFrameGrabber("audio-output.mp3");
        finalAudio.start();

        FFmpegFrameRecorder recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder("video-output.mp4", 1280, 720);
        recorder.setVideoCodec(avcodec.AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
        recorder.setAudioCodec(avcodec.AV_CODEC_ID_AAC);
        recorder.setSampleRate(finalAudio.getSampleRate());
        recorder.setAudioChannels(finalAudio.getAudioChannels());
        recorder.setFormat("mp4");
        recorder.start();

        Frame video1Frame;
        recorder.setFrameRate(video1Grabber.getFrameRate());
        while((video1Frame = video1Grabber.grabFrame())!= null) {
            recorder.record(video1Frame);
        }
        video1Grabber.stop();

        Frame video2Frame;
        recorder.setFrameRate(video2Grabber.getFrameRate());
        while((video2Frame = video2Grabber.grabFrame())!= null) {
            recorder.record(video2Frame);
        }
        video2Grabber.stop();

        finalAudio.stop();
        recorder.stop();
        fileOS.close();
        fileOS.flush();
```

Comment: That sounds like something that we can more easily get done with the ffmpeg program: http://bytedeco.org/javacpp-presets/ffmpeg/apidocs/org/bytedeco/ffmpeg/ffmpeg.html

Comment: @SamuelAudet I tried to use the ffmpeg concat command to merge two videos with different frame rates, but I am still facing the same issue as mentioned above. The second video becomes like a slow motion video and the length of the second video increases drastically. Kindly help